# Performance of Memento vs. in-memory database options

Tags: visual-studio-code, memento

As part of my VS code extension, I have a localdb I'd like to write and query values from.  I know there are many in-memory db options for JS/TS (lmdb, pouchdb, etc.). Are there any performance comparisons for VS code's own [local storage options](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage) specifically Memento storage? I assume Memento storage is probably SQL backed, but I'm not sure.

Assume that the data stored does not need to be shared across instances, and that security of the data is inconsequential.

I researched mentions in vs code's github issues/SO of local-db, in-memory db and the like.